# Drag and drop an ImageView onto a another ImageView

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview

I'm developing an android app where the user can drag an `ImageView` to another `ImageView`. The `ImageView` needs to be changed in to dragged `ImageView` if it meets a certain condition and if it doesnt it should snap back to where it was.I tried doing it but i can't get it to work.

code behind the xml file

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="2"
android:columnWidth="320dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:rowCount="14"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topleft"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="413dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:background="@drawable/shape" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_house"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/test_house" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topright"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="106dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    android:layout_row="13"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/house"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/house"
        android:layout_weight="0.26" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/face"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/face"
        android:layout_weight="0.24" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/duck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/duck"
        android:layout_weight="0.24" />

    </LinearLayout>

 </GridLayout>
```

code behind java file

```
public class cs_game_one extends Activity {

boolean state;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cs_game_one);
    findViewById(R.id.test_house).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.house).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.face).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.duck).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.topleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    findViewById(R.id.topright).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());


    }

private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new   View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {


    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
            View view = (View) e.getLocalState();
            if (view.getId() == R.id.house && v.getId() == R.id.test_house){                       
                ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                from.removeView(view);
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.house);

                state = true;

            } else {
                state =  false;
            }

        }
    return state;
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: are you seeing errors? Can you tell us what works and what doesn't, or if nothing at all happens when you touch the view?

Comment: I don't get any errors but when i drag the image and drop it just disappears without replacing the `ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

After `v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.house);` add this:
`v.invalidate();`
This tells your UI thread that it needs to redraw that view that you are trying to set to the house Drawable.

In your `else` statement, change to this:

```
state = false;
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //This will make it look like your dragged image snaps back to it's original spot.
```

The interesting thing about drag and drop in Android is that when you start the drag, it's just hiding the image you originally touched (`view` in your code) when the drag started. The image you see moving around the screen under your finger is actually the drag shadow. Thus by changing the visibility of `view` in your `else` statement, it looks like the image snaps back to where you started the drag.

Comment: thanks.I tried adding them but still it doesn't make any difference